# Two different Windows installations running the same colorscheme, different results

Tags: windows-7, vim, gvim, vimrc

I recently copied over my [Vim settings](https://github.com/mattalexx/dotfiles) to a new Windows computer.

I use a tweaked version of the [molokai vim theme](https://github.com/tomasr/molokai) that I named "[molokai-mine](https://github.com/mattalexx/dotfiles/blob/master/.vim/colors/molokai-mine.vim)". Here's what it should look like:

[image]

On my new computer, however, this is what it looks like:

[image]

What gives?

Comment: I'm sure you have already verified that they are actually running the same colorscheme, but I'd still recommend double checking by doing ":colorscheme" on both machines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all check your screen setting - aren't you using 256 colors on the second machine? Also check the monitor settings.

Then issue :colo vim command and it should read the same value.

Then compare both files using diff. They should be same.